Convergence in $\mathbb{L}_1$ implies convergence "perturbed" conditional expectations
Consider a sequence of conditional pdf's $p_n(y | x)$ on a Polish space $X \times Y$, endowed with its Borel sigma algebra. Suppose, as $n\rightarrow \infty$, in $\mathbb{L}_1$ (the following densities can be seen as mixtures of normals with weights functions $\omega_{k,n}(X)$, $\omega^*_k(X)$ that sum up to 1 almost surely for fixed $X$ and $n$):
$$ \sum_{k=1}^{\infty} \omega_{k,n} (X) \frac{1}{\sqrt{2 \pi \sigma^2_k}} \exp\left( -\frac{(y - \beta_{0,k,n} - \beta_{1,k,n} X)^2}{2 \sigma^2_k} \right) = p_n(y | X) \stackrel{\mathbb{L}_1}{\rightarrow} p_0(y | X) = \sum_{k=1}^{\infty} \omega^*_k (X) \frac{1}{\sqrt{2 \pi \sigma^2_{k,*}}} \exp\left( -\frac{(y - \beta^*_{0,k} - \beta^*_{1,k} X)^2}{2 \sigma^2_{k,*}} \right) $$
is then true that for a sequence of measurable function $f_n \stackrel{\mathbb{L}_1}{\rightarrow} f_0$ also the "perturbed" conditional expectations converge as follows:
$$  \sum_{k=1}^{\infty} \omega_{k,n} (X) (\beta_{0,k,n} + \beta_{1,k,n} (X+f_n(X)))   \stackrel{\mathbb{L}_1}{\rightarrow} \sum_{k=1}^{\infty} \omega^*_k (X) (\beta^*_{0,k} + \beta^*_{1,k} (X+f_0(X))) $$

The question as it stands is not understandable at all for me. What do all of the symbols mean? Somehow the LHS doesn't even depend on $n$? What is $\omega_k(X)$? What do you really mean by $N(\dots, \dots)$?

I added this corrections

It is better now, but I must say that I still don't understand the exact question. Is $X$ random? Why does nothing depend on $y$? Do you mean the density of the corresponding normal distribution by $N$?

I also wrote it now in a more precise way so that it is clear that I meant the densities of normals

Okay. So the $L^1$-convergence is meant just with right to $y$? What is the corresponding measure? Then why does your "perturbed" term not depend on $y$?

no the $\epsilon$-$L_1$-neighborhoods of a density $f_0$ are defined with respect to any measure $\nu$ with $supp(\nu) \subset X$ as follows: $$ \bigg{ f : \int | f( \cdot | x) - f_0( \cdot | x)|_1 d \nu(x) < \epsilon \bigg}$$ In the above mentioned case, the measure $\nu$ can be assumed to be the true measure according to which the $X$ are distributed. It can be also assumed it has a density $v(x)$, bounded away from 0 and infinity

Okay, and what measure do you have on $Y$? Are your "Polish spaces" just $\mathbb{R}$? It's a little bit tiring to ask for all that things which cannot be guessed from context. I suggest that you try to make the question understandable without having to ask so much, as I and probably others want to help but not worm everything out of you..

I don't want to come across as unnecessarily pedantic without being helpful, so I'm guessing what the question really means.
Under my guessed assumptions, the answer is in general no even for $f_n = f_0 = 0$ for all $n \in \mathbb{N}$.
For $n \in \mathbb{N}$, let $\beta_{0, 1, n} = 0$, $\beta_{0, 2, n} = n$, $\beta_{1, k, n} = 0$ and $\sigma_k^2 = 1$ for all $k \in \mathbb{N}$.
Also let $\omega_{1, n} = 1 - \frac{1}{n}$, $\omega_{2, n} =  \frac{1}{n}$ and $\omega_{k, n} = 0$ for $k \geq 2$.
Regarding the limit, let $\beta_{0, 1}^* = 0$ and $\beta_{1, k}^* = 0$ and $\sigma_k^2 = 1$ for all $k \in \mathbb{N}$.
Also let $\omega_1^* = 1$.
Then
$$
\int \, \nu(\mathrm{d}x) \, \Vert p_n(\cdot \vert x) - p_0(\cdot \vert x) \Vert_{L^1}
= \int \, \nu(\mathrm{d}x) \, \int_{\mathbb{R}} \, \mathrm{d}y \, \vert p_n(y \vert x) - p_0(y \vert x)\vert
\leq \frac{2}{n}
\xrightarrow[n \to \infty]{} 0
$$ but
$$
\int \, \nu(\mathrm{d}x) \, \left\vert \omega_{1, n} \beta_{0, 1, n} + \omega_{2, n} \beta_{0, 2, n} - \omega_{1}^* \beta_{0, 1}^* \right\vert
= \int \, \nu(\mathrm{d}x) \, \left\vert 0 + n \frac{1}{n} - 0\right\vert
= 1,
$$ hence the desired convergence does not hold.

But the weights do not sum up to 1, or do I misunderstand something?  So they are not conditional densities in the first place. In any case, I was indeed trying to work out the in which the $\beta$ coefficients lie in a bounded set. I think the statement is true if $XxY$ is a compact set in $\mathbb{R}^2$ by the uniqueness representation theorem of mixtures of normals. Thank you very much for your help in any case!

@GrandesJorasses Sorry, this was just a typo which is now corrected. About your more specialised statement I would have to think first.
